# Android drawable images for different resolutions

Tags: android, drawable

I remember seeing somewhere that there was some way, or some tool where you give it an image and it automatically scales and generates multiple images for different resolutions but I can't seem to find it.
Does anyone know what I'm describing and where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for, Android Asset Studio.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html